# ::eLearning store in Magento CE::

Tags: magento-1.8, product, magento-community, development, stores

How much is the feasibility for building/developing eLearning Store on Magento CE(1.8+)?

The store would contains products(online test for BANK, Engineering and other competative examination), on purchasing the user will be sent a link to there registered mail regarding the platform on which the online test would be conducted.

What is the best practice for defining the eLearning products w.r.t Magento??

Comment: You should have a look at downloadable products. You can include a link as sample and link for purchase there.

Comment: The products are not e-material like pdf or doc, but on user purchase, the user will get a link in there registered mail, which will redirect the user to appear in online test engine outside Magento. So what would be the category or best practice for defining the product?

Comment: Sure, you can either have a document download or a link included in downloadable products.